# Iterate through HTML DOM and get depth

Tags: javascript, html, dom

How is it possible to iterate through the HTML DOM and list all nodes with there depth in javascript.

Example:

```
<div>
    <img src="foo.jpg">
    <p>
        <span>bar</span>
    </p>
</div>
```

would result in

- div 0
- img 1
- p 1
- span 2

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Write a recursive function which tracks the depth:

```
function element_list(el,depth) {
    console.log(el+' '+depth);
    for(var i=0; i<el.children.length; i++) {
        element_list(el.children[i],depth+1);
    }
}
element_list(document,0);
```

---

As [CodeiSir](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33904153/901048) points out, this will also list text nodes, but we can filter them out by [testing the `nodeType`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/nodeType). Variations on this code will allow/ignore other node types as desired.

```
function element_list(el,depth) {
   if (el.nodeType === 3) return;
```

Comment: I took some time to make my answer, this one answer is missing some stuff out. When you actualy use it, it won't present the results he wanted.

Comment: @CodeiSir Seeing as how OP didn't provide any code at all, I wasn't trying to present anything more than a basic answer that would point him in the right direction. Good point about filtering out text nodes, though.

Comment: I was wondering whether you had edited this since you wrote it, but it appears not.  `el.children` will return only the elements, so no "text nodes" will be returned, although it will return `SPAN` elements.  You'd have to put `el.childNodes` if you did in fact want the text nodes to be printed out.  Other than that, this is simple and functional, although I could wish that `TreeWalker` [https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/createTreeWalker], which doesn't involve recursion, had a means of finding out the depth of the current node.

Comment: A sample [code](https://jsbin.com/hepijajiqu/edit?js,console) indenting the output.

Answer (score 5):

Note that the other answers are/where not realy correct ...

This will also filter out "TEXT" Nodes, and not output the BODY tag.

```js
function getDef(element, def) {
  var str = ""

  var childs = element.childNodes
  for (var i = 0; i < childs.length; ++i) {
    if (childs[i].nodeType != 3) {
      str += childs[i].nodeName + " " + def + "<br />"
      str += getDef(childs[i], def + 1)
    }
  }

  return str
}


// Example
document.body.innerHTML = getDef(document.body, 0)
```

```html
<div>
  <img src="foo.jpg">
  <p>
    <span>bar</span>
  </p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3):

Yes, you can! You would have to iterate and some logic to create this tree, but for your example, you could do something like:

```
var tracker = {};
Array.from(document.querySelectorAll("*")).forEach(node => {
    if (!tracker[node.tagName]) tracker[node.tagName] = 1;
    else tracker[node.tagName]++;
});
console.log(tracker);
```

You can modify this to run on a recrusive subset of childNodes. This just iterates the entire document.

Check [this fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/tpcv4ezu/) and open the console to see the output of `tracker` which counts and lists tag names. To add the depth, just grab the `parentNode.length` all the way up.

Here's an updated script which I *think* does the depth count propery;

```
var tracker = {};
var depth = 0;
var prevNode;
Array.from(document.querySelectorAll("*")).forEach(node => {
    if (!tracker[node.tagName]) tracker[node.tagName] = 1;
    else tracker[node.tagName]++;
    console.log("Node depth:", node.tagName, depth);
    if (node.parentNode != prevNode) depth++;
    prevNode = node;
});
console.log(tracker);
```

Answer (score 2):

`getElementDepth` returns the absolute depth of the node (starting from the `html` node), to get the difference of depth between two nodes you can just subtract an absolute depth from another.

```js
function getElementDepthRec(element,depth)
{
 if(element.parentNode==null)
     return depth;
    else
     return getElementDepthRec(element.parentNode,depth+1);
}
    
function getElementDepth(element)
{
    return getElementDepthRec(element,0);
}

function clickEvent() {
    alert(getElementDepth(document.getElementById("d1")));
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<div>
 <div id="d1">
 </div>
</div>

<button onclick="clickEvent()">calculate depth</button>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

My original solution walked each element up the DOM using a `while` loop to determine its depth:

```js
var el = document.querySelectorAll('body *'),  //all element nodes, in document order
    depth,
    output= document.getElementById('output'),
    obj;

for (var i = 0; i < el.length; i++) {
  depth = 0;
  obj = el[i];
  while (obj.parentNode !== document.body) {   //walk the DOM
    depth++;
    obj = obj.parentNode;
  }
  output.textContent+= depth + ' ' + el[i].tagName + '\n';
}
```

```html
<div>
  <img src="foo.jpg">
  <p>
    <span>bar</span>
  </p>
</div>
<hr>
<pre id="output"></pre>
```

---

I've come up with a new solution, which stores the depths of each element in an object.  Since [`querySelectorAll()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll) returns elements in document order, parent nodes always appear before child nodes.  So a child node's depth can be calculated as the depth of its parent node plus one.

This way, we can determine the depths in a single pass without recursion:

```js
var el = document.querySelectorAll('body *'),  //all element nodes, in document order
    depths= {                                  //stores the depths of each element
      [document.body]: -1                      //initialize the object
    },
    output= document.getElementById('output');

for (var i = 0; i < el.length; i++) {
  depths[el[i]] = depths[el[i].parentNode] + 1;
  output.textContent+= depths[el[i]] + ' ' + el[i].tagName + '\n';
}
```

```html
<div>
  <img src="foo.jpg">
  <p>
    <span>bar</span>
  </p>
</div>
<hr>
<pre id="output"></pre>
```

Answer (score 1):

Anyone looking for something which iterates through the tree under a node without using recursion* but which also gives you depth (relative to the head node) ... as well as sibling-ancestor coordinates at all times:

```
function walkDOM( headNode ){
  const stack = [ headNode ];
  const depthCountDowns = [ 1 ];
  while (stack.length > 0) {
    const node = stack.pop();
    console.log( '\ndepth ' + ( depthCountDowns.length - 1 ) + ', node: ');
    console.log( node );

    let lastIndex = depthCountDowns.length - 1;
    depthCountDowns[ lastIndex ] = depthCountDowns[ lastIndex ] - 1;

    if( node.childNodes.length ){
        depthCountDowns.push( node.childNodes.length );
        stack.push( ... Array.from( node.childNodes ).reverse() );
    }

    while( depthCountDowns[ depthCountDowns.length - 1 ] === 0 ){
        depthCountDowns.splice( -1 );
    }
  }
} 

walkDOM( el );
```

PS it will be understood that I've put in `> 0` and `=== 0` to try to improve clarity... first can be omitted and second can be replaced with leading `!` of course.

* look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24916033/595305) for the appalling truth about the cost of recursion in JS (contemporary implementations at 2018-02-01 anyway!)

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by using Jquery

```
$('#divId').children().each(function () {
     // "this" is the current element
});
```

and the html should be like the following:

```
<div id="divId">
<img src="foo.jpg">
<p>
    <span>bar</span>
</p>
```

Comment: Introducing jQuery into a question that isn't calling for it is not a good idea. It can be quickly downvoted. Also, this only alert (use console.log) the `value` (which none of those elements has, because they're not input elements) of the elements, not their document node depth.

Comment: Yes this is true, but "this" is the current element. I will remove the value

Answer (score 0):

```
(() => {
    const el = document.querySelectorAll('body *');
    const depths = new Map();
    depths.set(document.body, -1)
    el.forEach((e) => {
        const p = e.parentNode;
        const d = depths.get(p);
        depths.set(e, d + 1);
    })
    return depths;
})()
```

This is `Rick Hitchcock`s answer but using Map instead of object

Results in `Map(5) {body => -1, div => 0, img => 1, p => 1, span => 2}`