# Why is this wrapped function call faster than a regular function?

Tags: javascript, node.js

Executing this recursive fibonacci function takes around 9.5 seconds on my machine, using a traditional approach:

```js
const fib = n => {
  if (n == 1) return 0;
  if (n == 2) return 1;
  return fib(n - 1) + fib(n - 2);
};

console.log(fib(45));
```

```sh
➜ time node index.js
701408733
node index.js  9,50s user 0,04s system 99% cpu 9,566 total
```

However, when I wrap the body of the function in another function that gets executed right away, execution drops to 7.5 seconds:

```js
const fib = n => {
  return (() => {
    if (n == 1) return 0;
    if (n == 2) return 1;
    return fib(n - 1) + fib(n - 2);
  })();
};

console.log(fib(45));
```

```sh
➜ time node index.js
701408733
node index.js  7,58s user 0,25s system 99% cpu 7,852 total
```

This is a huge speedup (~30%!), but I cannot figure out why wrapping the function would make this difference.

Comment: it maybe worth profiling it using devtools

Comment: also, it maybe worth using a fresh node instance each time - things get warmm

Comment: Good idea. I'll give this a try.

Comment: How often did you do this test?

Comment: why does one run 9566 times and the other one 7852?

Comment: @CallumLinington I tried it on two different machines, randomizing the input. Same result every time

Comment: @derpirscher like 10 times, on two machines

Comment: @Ifaruki i think the numbers is the total time, not the number of runs

Comment: check it https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/276346/why-is-the-latter-function-10-faster-although-it-must-create-the-variables-over

Comment: @MomoSetti in his case it's the exact opposite. I suspect it has to do with recursion.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is indeed a very strange behaviour.

After some digging, I see that it's mentioned in a few past questions (for example, [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24915428/does-javascript-performance-suffer-from-deep-recursion)) that JS performs worse with recursion, such as in `fib1`.

Now the question that rises is whether `fib2` isn't a recursive function. I assume that because it creates a new anonymous function - rather than using the same memory reference to `fib2` - it's practically "less recursive" and therefore performs better.

**EDIT**: After reading [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54719548/tail-call-optimization-implementation-in-javascript-engines) it looks like what's going on is some sort of Tail Call handling (`fib2` uses tail recursion, as opposed to `fib1`, where each call is calculated before the result can be returned).

Another interesting observation is that - to a certain degree - the recursion does work better, but then it's getting exponentially slower.

```js
function fib1(n) {
  if (n === 1) return 0;
  if (n === 2) return 1;
  return fib1(n - 1) + fib1(n - 2);
};

function fib2(n) {
  return (() => {
    if (n === 1) return 0;
    if (n === 2) return 1;
    return fib2(n - 1) + fib2(n - 2);
  })();
};

function calculateAverageTime(func, iterations = 5) {
  let sum = 0;

  [...Array(iterations)].forEach(() => {
    const start = new Date();
    func();
    const finish = new Date();
    sum += (finish - start);
  });

  return Math.round(sum / iterations);
}

function compare(i) {
  const fib1RunTime = calculateAverageTime(() => fib1(i));
  const fib2RunTime = calculateAverageTime(() => fib2(i));
  console.log(`Difference for fib(${i}) is ${(fib2RunTime - fib1RunTime)}ms`);
}

[10, 20, 30, 40].forEach(i => compare(i));
```

Answer (score 0):

```
return (() => {
```

I am not sure.. but probably this string wait for a response before the program control this line:

```
if (n == 1)
```

The program lodge a small portion of memory (stack) before the program starts to control if "n" is effectively "== 1" and put all the functions in that portion of memory.

Then start the function.